# How to generate smaller unique number from larger (11 bytes) unique number? General C

Tags: c, numbers, unique

I have several devices. Each of them has its unique ID composed of 11 bytes, like: 0x34 0x57 0x36 0x31 0x38 0x39 0x15 0x0e 0x00 0x0f 0x00. I would like to generate unique number (0-32767 or 0-65535) to delay answer when FindDevices command is broadcasted. When devices start to answer at the same moment there is RS485 bus contention problem so I would like to avoid that.

My first attempt was to sum all the 11 bytes of unique ID, call srand(sum) to seed generator and then call rand() to get my value.
But it's unfortunately poor solution and in my batch of devices I've got 2 devices with unique ID but the same "(not so)unique" number :(

UID1: 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0e 00 0f 00
sum: 405 decimal
generated number: 23860

UID2: 34 57 33 31 35 39 04 18 00 1c 00
sum: 405 decimal
generated number: 23860

Devices don't know what number was generated in other devices or what unique IDs they have so they can't simply compare them.

Any idea how to generate such unique number (0-32767 or 0-65535)?

**Edit:**
List of unique IDs (as hex) of batch from my bench:

`01. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 02 00
02. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 06 00
03. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 0A 00
04. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 0E 00
05. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0A 00 14 00
06. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0A 00 1C 00
07. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 09 00 23 00
08. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0A 00 24 00
09. 34 57 36 31 38 39 0E 1D 00 1A 00
10. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 09 00
11. 34 57 33 31 35 39 04 10 00 20 00
12. 34 57 33 31 35 39 04 18 00 1C 00
13. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 0F 00
14. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 13 00
15. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 17 00
16. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0E 00 1F 00
17. 34 57 36 31 38 39 15 0A 00 25 00`
 It looks that they are unique but many bytes are repeated/constant. Good solution should generate values placed in whole range even if input values are close to each other :)

**Edit2:**
Here are results for all solutions from your answers:

```
Test results:
OP:  1977, H1L: 14759, H1H: 13938, H2L:  7189, H2H: 36686, H3L: 14759, H3H: 13938, H4:  2652, PRS: 61086
OP:  3669, H1L: 13735, H1H: 12914, H2L:  8213, H2H: 37710, H3L: 13735, H3H: 12914, H4:  6748, PRS: 25852
OP:  5361, H1L: 16807, H1H: 15986, H2L:  5141, H2H: 34638, H3L: 16807, H3H: 15986, H4: 10844, PRS: 40974
OP:  7053, H1L: 15783, H1H: 14962, H2L:  6165, H2H: 35662, H3L: 15783, H3H: 14962, H4: 14940, PRS: 19836
OP:  7899, H1L: 18507, H1H: 25943, H2L:  3441, H2H: 24681, H3L: 18507, H3H: 25943, H4: 21076, PRS:  4898
OP: 11283, H1L: 20555, H1H: 27991, H2L:  1393, H2H: 22633, H3L: 20555, H3H: 27991, H4: 29268, PRS: 10065
OP: 13821, H1L:   391, H1H: 26260, H2L: 21557, H2H: 24364, H3L:   391, H3H: 26260, H4: 36434, PRS: 63904
OP: 14667, H1L: 30795, H1H: 38231, H2L: 23902, H2H: 12393, H3L: 30795, H3H: 38231, H4: 37460, PRS: 46300
OP: 15513, H1L: 23009, H1H: 40628, H2L: 31688, H2H:  9996, H3L: 23009, H3H: 40628, H4: 27066, PRS: 21678
OP: 21322, H1L: 17063, H1H: 16242, H2L:  4885, H2H: 34382, H3L: 17063, H3H: 16242, H4:  9820, PRS: 60787
OP: 22168, H1L: 31736, H1H: 54522, H2L: 22961, H2H: 61623, H3L: 31736, H3H: 54522, H4: 32801, PRS: 20737
OP: 23860, H1L:  3760, H1H: 10032, H2L: 18188, H2H: 40592, H3L:  3760, H3H: 10032, H4: 28721, PRS: 50696
OP: 23860, H1L: 15527, H1H: 14706, H2L:  6421, H2H: 35918, H3L: 15527, H3H: 14706, H4: 15964, PRS: 28319
OP: 25552, H1L: 10407, H1H:  9586, H2L: 11541, H2H: 41038, H3L: 10407, H3H:  9586, H4: 20060, PRS: 60097
OP: 27244, H1L:  9383, H1H:  8562, H2L: 12565, H2H: 42062, H3L:  9383, H3H:  8562, H4: 24156, PRS:  5512
OP: 30628, H1L: 11431, H1H: 10610, H2L: 10517, H2H: 40014, H3L: 11431, H3H: 10610, H4: 32348, PRS: 55107
OP: 31474, H1L: 30539, H1H: 37975, H2L: 24158, H2H: 12649, H3L: 30539, H3H: 37975, H4: 38484, PRS:  4379
OP: 20035, H1L:     0, H1H:     0, H2L: 21948, H2H: 50624, H3L:     0, H3H:     0, H4:     0, PRS: 26124
```

*OP* is my original method which is poor and generates non-unique numbers for UIDs that were listed.
*H1L* and *H1H* are simplified solutions presented by chux.
*H2L, H2H, H3L, H3H* are my modifications (adding ~ to lower or upper part) to see if it produces better results.
*H4* is solution presented by alain.
*PRS* is Pearson returning uint16_t suggested by mattinbits.

**And the winner is... PRS!** :) All your suggestions generate unique numbers from listed UIDs so they are correct but **Pearson hashing** offers best variance of results (checked in Excel ;) ).
**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: There are some advantages of generating numbers in the range `[0 ... some_prime_minus_1]`, `(some_prime_minus_1 <= 32767 or 655535)`. I would take the 88 bits into a `64-bit unsigned long long ^ 24-bit unsigned long` and then `%some_prime_minus` as my simple hash function.

Comment: Could you please write something more about your idea? Or some pseudo-code? Sounds interesting but I'm not sure if I get it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is effectively find a hash for your ids where the hash output is smaller than the input, so there will always be a risk of collisions, ie two device ids producing the same short id. Nevertheless, you'll have better luck using a proper hashing function than your sum approach. Just look for a simple 8 or 16 bit hash function and use that. E.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing

Comment: Even so, initializing random generator with different seeds does not guarantee different generated numbers.

Comment: I'm advocating any use of a randomiser. The hash output itself can be used as the ID if an 8 or 16 bit hash is used.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try :) Thanks for the link to wiki!

Answer (score 4):

To generate a *unique number* in a range of 15 or 16 bits from larger numbers (11 bytes or 88 bits) is a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) and prone to collisions as happened with OP's generated number 23860.

Summing all the 11 bytes is very weak as the sum of the 11 bytes is in the range of 0 to 11*255 or 2805 with very uneven distribution.  So code only generates 2806 different seeds for `srand()`.  It would have been better to use a wider integer grouping than 8-bit.  Recommend 64-bit groups exclusive-or'd with each other.

Using `srand() / rand()` is a method but has weakness *for consistency*: 1) Portability: same data on different platforms may yield different numbers as C specifies little about `rand()` method.  2) As it requires 2 functions sharing a global state variable, code must insure another thread/interrupt does not mess things up or that these calls mess up consistency in other functions using `rand()`.  A big problem with `rand()` is on systems where `RAND_MAX` is 32767, its minimum specified value, and code is attempting [0...65536].

I found *consistency* important as being able to use the same test code on multiple platforms: a significant advantage in code maintenance.

[@mattinbits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710288/2410359) well recommends a good  8/16 bit solution.  Why re-invent the wheel?  Yet I do not drive on chariot tires, so ...

If OP does not appear to really need a identifier in the *entire* range of [0...32767] or [0...65536] (Did OP mean 65535?), consider a simple portable repeatable hash method that relies on `%` by a [prime](http://www.onlineconversion.com/prime.htm) near the limit to well mix up the bits.

```
// return numbers 0 ... 32748 or 0 ... 65536
unsigned long Hash(const unsigned char ID[11]) {
  unsigned long long Upper;
  unsigned long Lower;
  Upper = (ID[0]*1ULL<<56) | (ID[1]*1ULL<<48) | (ID[2]*1ULL<<40) | (ID[3]*1ULL<<32) |
      (ID[4]*1UL<<24)  | (ID[5]*1UL<<16) | (ID[6]*1U<<8) | ID[7];
  Lower = (ID[8]*1UL<<16) | (ID[9]*1U<<8) | ID[10];
  // Greatest prime <= 32768
  #define Prime_LE_32768 32749
  return (Upper ^ Lower) % Prime_LE_32768;

  // or 
  // Greatest prime <= 65537
  #define Prime_LE_65537 65537
  return (Upper ^ Lower) % Prime_LE_65537;
}
```

[Edit] with potential simplifications.

```
unsigned Hash(const uint8_t ID[11], unsigned prime) {
  uint64_t H[2] = {0};
  memcpy(H, ID, 11);
  return (H[0] ^ H[1]) % prime;
}

const unsigned char ID[][11] = {
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x09, 0x00, 0x23, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x0E, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1A, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x33, 0x31, 0x35, 0x39, 0x04, 0x10, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x33, 0x31, 0x35, 0x39, 0x04, 0x18, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x13, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x17, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x00 },
    { 0x34, 0x57, 0x36, 0x31, 0x38, 0x39, 0x15, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x25, 0x00 },
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } };

#define Prime_LE_32768 32749
#define Prime_LE_65536 65521u
void test() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof ID / sizeof ID[0]; i++) {
    const char *comma = "";
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
      printf("%s%02X", comma, ID[i][j]);
      comma = "-";
    }
    printf(" %5u", Hash(ID[i], Prime_LE_32768));
    printf(" %5u\n", Hash(ID[i], Prime_LE_65536));
  }
  puts("");
}
```

> Output

```
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-02-00 14759 13938
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-06-00 13735 12914
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-0A-00 16807 15986
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-0E-00 15783 14962
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0A-00-14-00 18507 25943
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0A-00-1C-00 20555 27991
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-09-00-23-00   391 26260
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0A-00-24-00 30795 38231
34-57-36-31-38-39-0E-1D-00-1A-00 23009 40628
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-09-00 17063 16242
34-57-33-31-35-39-04-10-00-20-00 31736 54522
34-57-33-31-35-39-04-18-00-1C-00  3760 10032
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-0F-00 15527 14706
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-13-00 10407  9586
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-17-00  9383  8562
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0E-00-1F-00 11431 10610
34-57-36-31-38-39-15-0A-00-25-00 30539 37975
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution where every device generates an ID on its own, like with the "hash" approach, has the advantage that it works without communication. On the other hand the number has to be large enough such that collisions are very unlikely. 16 bits is not much.

One practical way I see, is to use a number based on a property of the device, like a processor serial number, or a RS485 bus address (but I suspect you want to use the ID we're talking about for exactly this purpose).
If the 11-byte unique ID, or a serial number you have access to, is not random, you can use that non-randomness to make a better hash function than any general-purpose one.
This is because a general-purpose hash function has to mix the bits evenly, because it doesn't know which bits vary more than others. If you know which bits vary the most, you can use this knowledge to build a better hash function. For example if you have a counter, the least significant bits are the ones to choose for a "unique" ID.

If this is not possible, I would try to make a communication scheme that detects colliding IDs. This should be possible because every device sees all the communication on the RS485 bus.

Edit: Based on the example data I would select these bits:

```
00 00 00 00 01 00 1B 1F 00 3F 00
```

and implement a hash function like:

```
unsigned short hash(const unsigned char ID[11]) {
    return (ID[9] << 10)
            | ((ID[6] & 0x18) << 5)
            | ((ID[6] & 0x03) << 6)
            | ((ID[7] & 0x1F) << 1)
            | (ID[4] & 0x01);
}
```

This function is very likely to produce unique identifiers for devices that are added in the future.

Comment: I do use processor unique serial number. It looks like this: `uniqueID[0] = LOTNUM0; 
uniqueID[1] = LOTNUM1;
 uniqueID[2] = LOTNUM2;
 uniqueID[3] = LOTNUM3;
 uniqueID[4] = LOTNUM4;
 uniqueID[5] = LOTNUM5;

 uniqueID[6] = WAFNUM;
 uniqueID[7] = COORDX0;
 uniqueID[8] = COORDX1;
 uniqueID[9] = COORDY0;
 uniqueID[10] = COORDY1;` So bytes 6 to 10 are more likely to change for batch of MCUs :) In standard RS485 reading is disabled when writing to cut off echoing and re-parsing communication but I could enable reding while writing just for this case to make it even more collision-proof

Comment: Yes, I think combining both is a good idea, select the most varying bits *and* detect collisions.

Comment: I have added list of UIDs in first post and in fact it's much simplier if we look at numbers we are talking about :) I.e COORDY1 and COORDX1 looks to be always zero... Maybe their wafers aren't so big to increment that part but they wanted to be 7nm process ready ;)